# Expand root partition arch

Tags: archlinux, partition

I have just installed Arch to a 8GB SD card, but it only uses c. 2GB of the disk. How do I expand it to fill the whole card, like rasp-config does? Is there some way to put rasp-config on Arch?

Answer (score 0):

```
resize2fs - ext2/ext3/ext4 file system resizer
```

comes to mind. still, this is a duplicate, please, refer to the previous similar questions for details.